# Vector Icon in 48dp also in 64dp?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-drawable, android-jetpack

I have an vector icon like:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="48dp"
        android:height="48dp"
        android:viewportWidth="48"
        android:viewportHeight="48">
  <path
          android:pathData="....."
          android:fillColor="#ffffff"
          android:fillType="evenOdd"/>
</vector>
```

what has 48dp. The icons for phone are designed in 48dp x 48dp, but the tablet icons are designed in 64dp x 64dp.

**How can I upscalde this vector icon to 64dp x 64dp in code?** I would prefer Jetpack Compose solutions..

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether device is mobile or tablet like this:

**Solution1**: In case you want to keep only 1 resource and change size according to condition

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val isTablet = isTablet(context)
Icon(
   painterResource = painterResource(R.drawable.mobileIcon),
   modifier = Modifier.size(if(isTablet) 64.dp else 48.dp)
)
```

**Solution2**: In case you want to change resource according to condition

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val isTablet = isTablet(context)
Icon(
   painterResource = if(isTablet) painterResource(R.drawable.tabletIcon) else painterResource(R.drawable.mobileIcon),
   modifier = Modifier.size(if(isTablet) 64.dp else 48.dp)
)
```

Dependency that you will require to get `isTablet()` function:

`com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.2.0`